# RichText GUI selection color issue when GUI minimized

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I have simple Win-form GUI in C# which display the text in red or Green depended upon the value received. The RichText display the text correctly as long as the i do not minimize the GUI. When the GUI is minimized, the text shown in Text window is in black color (only data that was processed when GUI was minimized). when the GUI is maximized the text color for the data shown correctly again.

Please let me know what is wrong here.

```
Here is my code:



LogMessageWindow.Find(message);
LogMessageWindow.SelectionColor = Color.Red;  /// if message&2==0 set color to Red otherwise set color to green
LogMessageWindow.SuspendLayout();
LogMessageWindow.Focus();
LogMessageWindow.AppendText(message + ".\n");
LogMessageWindow.ScrollToCaret();*
```

Comment: Your posted code doesn't reproduce that issue.  Remove the SuspendLayout, Focus and ScrollToCaret lines — those aren't necessary.  Unclear why you are calling Find as well.

Comment: I does't work for me. i am using .net 3.5.  I need ScrollToCaret to keep the focus on current log (text) being shown in text window

Comment: ScrollToCarat wouldn't be the issue regardless.  You have to post code that duplicates the problem for us.  Try recreating the problem in a new project with minimum code.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have:

```
LogMessageWindow.Find(message);
```

This line is useless: you are Appending a new chunk of Text. Searching for it before appending it won't do much (maybe locate an identical string. Then what?).

```
LogMessageWindow.SuspendLayout();
```

`SuspendLayout()` can be useful if you're adding/appending a large selection of lines of text in batch. When you're finished, you should `ResumeLayout()`. Doesn't seem to be needed here.

```
LogMessageWindow.Focus();
```

Moving the Focus on the RTB control doesn't accomplish anything special. And if the container Form is minimized... Since you're adding text in a procedure, the focus is not needed.

A couple of things you can do.

**Using a method**, pass a reference to the RichTextBox that is used for this task, the color to use and the text to be appended.
 Here the new text color is defined as `Color? color`, so if you pass `null`, the control `ForeColor` is used.

```
RTBAppendWithColor(LogMessageWindow, 
                 ((message & 2) == 0) ? Color.Red : Color.Green, 
                   message.ToString() + "\n");

private void RTBAppendWithColor(RichTextBox rtb, Color? color, string AppendedText)
{
    int sLenght = AppendedText.Length;

    rtb.AppendText(AppendedText);
    rtb.Select(rtb.Text.Length - sLenght, sLenght);
    if (color != null)
        rtb.SelectionColor = (Color)color;
    rtb.ScrollToCaret();
}
```

**Using an Extension**.
Create a static Class with a static Method that references a RichTextBox object. This method will be a new method of any RichTextBox you create.

```
LogMessageWindow.AppendWithColor(((message & 2) == 0) ? Color.Red : Color.Green, 
                                   message.ToString() + "\n");

public static class RTBExtensions
{
    public static void AppendWithColor(this RichTextBox rtb, Color? color, string AppendedText)
    {
        int sLenght = AppendedText.Length;

        rtb.AppendText(AppendedText);
        rtb.Select(rtb.Text.Length - sLenght, sLenght);
        if (color != null)
            rtb.SelectionColor = (Color)color;

        rtb.ScrollToCaret();
    }
}
```

If you using **FrameWork 3.5**, the selection text will probably remain selected even after `ScrollToCaret()` is called. If it looks ugly, add:

```
rtb.SelectionStart = rtb.Text.Length;
```

before `rtb.ScrollToCaret()`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks al for yur valuable feedback. i was able to get this done by suing this code. 

`` LogMessageWindow.SelectionStart = LogMessageWindow.TextLength;                                  LogMessageWindow.SelectionLength = 0;            LogMessageWindow.SelectionColor = Color.Red;                      LogMessageWindow.SuspendLayout();LogMessageWindow.AppendText(message + ".\n");                  LogMessageWindow.ScrollToCaret();                       `                  LogMessageWindow.ResumeLayout() ``